# List forks with Github API v3

Tags: github-api, git-fork

I'm trying to list all forks of a repository with the Github API (with a valid personal access token):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/forks/
```

but it returns a not found error:

```
documentation_url: "https://developer.github.com/v3", 
message: "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the trailing slash:

`https://api.github.com/repos/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/forks`

Comment: A link to the corresponding docs for reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks