# How to list all fork Git URLs via GitHub API?

Tags: shell, curl, github-api

I'd like to list all forks and their URLs of specific GitHub repository programmatically through API. I can't see them all on the page, since it has [too many forks](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/network/members) to display on the website.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Why does this need to be re-documented on SO? GitHub's API docs are pretty good, and they're kept up-to-date.

Comment: Couldn't find it on SO, docs weren't clear, so I've clarified it, with some extra `jq` processing.

Comment: What was unclear in the docs? You're calling exactly the endpoint they tell you to, and have provided no additional information.

Comment: I was searching at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ and I couldn't find it quickly (the page is too long). It's always obvious when you find it. Searching in Google is quicker.

Comment: It's literally the first hit for "GitHub api list forks". Second is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516921/list-forks-with-github-api-v3. It's also listed in the page you were looking at (search in page for "fork").

Comment: Maybe I was blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of forks can be listed by [`/repos/:owner/:repo/forks` API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/) call.

To list URLs, the following command can help (sorted by stars):

```
curl -sq "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/forks?sort=stargazers" | jq '.[]|.html_url'
```

<sup>Note: Change OWNER and REPO with appropriate values.</sup>